# Thin client session state provider for ASP.NET

Tags: ignite

The C# IgniteSessionStateStoreProvider appears to be launching an entire instance of a JVM in-process in order to run a ignite node. I was wondering if it would be feasible to create a lightweight provider that talks to the cluster nodes, but that isn't a full node itself, i.e. doesn't require an in-process JVM.

By feasible I mean is there some fundamental architectural reason why there can't be a lightweight/thin provider?

Answer (score 3):

> is there some fundamental architectural reason why there can't be a lightweight/thin provider

We just used Ignite.NET API to create the provider, and that API starts a JVM in process. Advantage is this works very fast.

Thin client mode is coming in Ignite.NET 2.4 (expected in January). I've filed a ticket to add thin session store: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-7269

Comment: Thanks Pavel. I think a thin .NET client would be a big boost for Ignite. I'm looking at a range of options right now and they all have issues, a thin ignite client would put it above the other options right now.

Comment: @redcalx Thin client is already implemented, you can try nightly build right now: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/IGNITE/Nightly+Builds. Thin API is limited to cache for now, there are plans to add other features eventually. See `Ignition.StartClient`.

Comment: Does the cache support reliable storage? I.e. guaranteed to live until a command to delete the entry, or some expiry time assigned to the entry (with ability to update). For session state we don't need persistence to disk, so long as the entry is replicated (i.e. robust to any one node failing), it's generally OK for it to be in RAM. Or do I have to worry about cache eviction, e.g. upon memory pressure.

Comment: @redcalx there is no eviction unless you configure it. Data won't be lost.

Comment: FYI the nightly builds aren't producing a final build artifact currently. So I ran the maven build process on the latest from git but it failed partway through.

Comment: @redcalx .NET nightly build works fine, latest NuGet is 10 hours old: https://www.myget.org/feed/apache-ignite-net-nightly/package/nuget/Apache.Ignite

Comment: By the way, use modules\platforms\dotnet\build.bat to build from sources

Comment: Yeh the .NET client stuff is fine, but I need a v2.4 node to connect to to try it out. If I connect to a 2.3 node then it reports an unexpected client type error. It looks the nightly builds stopped producing the zip output in May 2017. See here:  https://builds.apache.org/view/H-L/view/Ignite/job/Ignite-nightly/   Is there an easy way to compile and run Ignite from source?

Comment: Thanks. I build the server from master branch, but still get the following error when attempting to connection with the .NET thin client "IgniteException: Unknown client type: 2". It looks to me like I need to get latest from a different (version 2.4) branch.

Comment: Forget that - I hadn't updated the IGNITE_HOME environment variable - it was still pointing at a 2.3.x build.

Comment: Looks like the SessionProvider for the thin client has not been implemented.  Any ideas on when it will be?